# SQL Linestring with multiple coordinates - can I use each location for distance calculations?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, spatial

I am trying to figure out if I can use a LineString with multiple coordinates, and calculate distances between each of the items in linestring, and another table with coordinates:

I have a few locations that I need to visit for e.g.

```
   A1 40.7120879 -73.9113197
   A2 40.7828647 -73.9653551
   A3 40.740777  -73.841136
```

I want to find out distance between these linestring locations and the other locations I will stop at

```
B1 40.7029334,-73.6208314
B2 40.7037142,-73.6086649
B3 40.7088981,-73.6137852
B4 40.7133267,-73.6056991
B5 40.7185586,-73.6007205
```

e.g.

```
A1 B1 - xxa meters
A1 B2 - xxb meters
A1 B3 - xxc meters
A1 B4 - xxd meters
A1 B5 - xxe meters 

A2 B1 - xya meters
A2 B2 - xyb meters
A3 B3 - xyc meters
A4 B4 - xyd meters
A5 B5 - xye meters
```

etc

```
CREATE TABLE SpatialTable 
    ( id int IDENTITY (1,1),
    GeogCol1 geography
);
GO

INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeogCol1)
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(40.7120879 -73.9113197, 40.7828647 -73.9653551, 40.740777, -73.841136)', 4326))


CREATE TABLE Route
    ( id int IDENTITY (1,1),
    Latitude float,
    Longitude float 
);
GO


Insert into Route(Latitude,Longitude)
values
(40.7029334,-73.6208314),
(40.7037142,-73.6086649),
(40.7088981,-73.6137852),
(40.7133267,-73.6056991),
(40.7185586,-73.6007205)
```

Comment: does it have to be in SQL, or can you work with a c# answer?

Comment: at this point i'm desperate so C# will do please :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt function for this (that I am aware of at least), but something like this should give you the results you are looking for.

```
--Index of point on linestring
DECLARE  @i INT = 1

--Output
DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE (LinePointNumber INT, PointID INT, Distance FLOAT)

--Identifier for the individual points
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @g GEOGRAPHY

--Linestring
DECLARE @geogcol GEOGRAPHY = (SELECT TOP 1 GeogCol1 FROM SpatialTable)

--loop through each point on the linestring
WHILE @i <= @geogcol.STNumPoints()
BEGIN
  --turn points into geography and loop through the collection
  --if you just cast a float to a varchar it will truncate, so cast to a decimal first to prevent that
  DECLARE pointcursor CURSOR FOR SELECT id, GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(CAST(Longitude AS DECIMAL(15,10)) AS VARCHAR(15)) + ' ' + CAST(CAST(Latitude AS DECIMAL(15,10)) AS VARCHAR(15)) + ')', 4326)
  OPEN pointcursor
  FETCH NEXT FROM pointcursor INTO @id, @g
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    --STPointN returns that point, the the distance is STDistance
    INSERT INTO @ResultTable (LinePointNumber, PointID, Distance) VALUES (@i, @id, @g.STDistance(@geogcol.STPointN(@i)))

    FETCH NEXT FROM pointcursor INTO @id, @g
  END
  CLOSE pointcursor
  DEALLOCATE pointcursor
  SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @ResultTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Hcaelxxam has just beat me to a solution - and in native SQL.  Never-the-less, I've worked it up for you so here it is.

Given a helper class of

```
public class MyPoint
{
    public MyPoint(string title, SqlGeography location)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Location = location;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public SqlGeography Location { get; set; }
}
```

Use the following code:

```
// The line, or route consisting of "waypoints"
        SqlGeography lineString = SqlGeography.STLineFromText(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars("LINESTRING(40.7120879 -73.9113197, 40.7828647 -73.9653551, 40.740777 -73.841136)"), 4326);

        // A container for all lookups
        List<MyPoint> stopLocations = new List<MyPoint>();

        // A container for all waypoints in the route
        List<MyPoint> wayPoints = new List<MyPoint>();

        // Add the stop locations
        stopLocations.Add(new MyPoint("B1", SqlGeography.Point(-73.6208314, 40.7029334, 4326)));
        stopLocations.Add(new MyPoint("B2", SqlGeography.Point(-73.6086649, 40.7037142, 4326)));
        stopLocations.Add(new MyPoint("B3", SqlGeography.Point(-73.6137852, 40.7088981, 4326)));
        stopLocations.Add(new MyPoint("B4", SqlGeography.Point(-73.6056991, 40.7133267, 4326)));
        stopLocations.Add(new MyPoint("B5", SqlGeography.Point(-73.6007205, 40.7185586, 4326)));

        // Add the waypoints
        for (int i = 1; i < (lineString.STNumPoints() + 1); i++)
        {
            wayPoints.Add(new MyPoint("A" + i, SqlGeography.Point(lineString.STPointN(i).Lat.Value, lineString.STPointN(i).Long.Value, lineString.STSrid.Value)));
        }

        // Join the data (essentially a cross-join) and calculate distances
        var joinAndCalculate = (
            from wp in wayPoints
            from sl in stopLocations
            select new
            {
                WayPointTitle = wp.Title,
                StopLocationTitle = sl.Title,
                DistanceInMetres = wp.Location.STDistance(sl.Location)
            }
            ).OrderBy(x => x.WayPointTitle).ThenBy(x => x.StopLocationTitle)
            .ToList()
                               ;
        // Print to the console, for testing
        foreach (var data in joinAndCalculate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.WayPointTitle + "\t" + data.StopLocationTitle + "\t" + data.DistanceInMetres);
        }
```

If not you, it may help someone else.

Comment: This is pretty cool man, I have never used this stuff in c#, so its pretty cool to see it used like this.  I have a couple questions though if you don't mind; The first is when you add the waypoints you refer to STPointN(1) rather than STPointN(i), is that just a goof or am I misunderstanding what you did?  My other question is, do you know how hard would it be to take something like this and turn it into a CLR function?  I have never done that, but this seems like a perfect use.

Comment: @hcaelxxam No problem at all.  Thanks for noticing that, it should be "i" not "1" so I've updated the code!  You have to start at 1 because all Geography methods are 1-based indexes.  In theory, it shouldn't be too hard to implement as a CLR function.  I've never given it a go, always preferring to use SQL as the data store and implementing business needs / logic in c# where possible.  In the OP's case, a CLR may actually work better if the solution is preferred in SQL direct.

Comment: @hcaelxxam If you can implement as a CLR function, I should add it's likely to improve performance.  SQL hates cursors from a performance persepective, but without implementing outside of SQL, it's pretty much impossible to accomplish what the OP wants without one.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have been working on an ETL process that includes something remarkably similar to what OP is doing ([if you care](http://i.imgur.com/VWMMv3G.png))and I have to use cursors all over the place.  If figuring out how to do it in C# will improve performance (right now, it looks like to process all the backlog data it will take over a week straight) I will definitely need to look into it.

Comment: No problem at all.  Love the image, reminds me of one of those really old rope bridges you see in the old films! :-) It's definitely worth a shot looking into CLR functions.  SQL's power is in working with large sets (i'm sure you know that), so relieving it of the more "mundane" stuff that it wasn't designed for should in the main improve performance.

Comment: holy smoke double awesomeness from everybody, thank you so much. I am taking everything in now and experimenting with this new knowledge, thank you  JonBellamy and @hcaelxxam

Comment: @PeterPitLock likewise.